# How to remove a specific div from divs with same class name?

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove a specific div from divs with same class name ?

```
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del1' /></div>
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del2' /></div>
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del3' /></div>
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del4' /></div>
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del5' /></div>
.<.div class='order_number'><input type='button' class='order_del' value='del6' /></div>
```

I'd like to remove second div or what I chose.

```
jQuery(".order_del").live('click', function(){
    // ??????
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: 1) look for "jquery remove". 2) don't use live but on.

Comment: Which element are you trying to remove, the one that's clicked? Or a descendant, or an entirely different element? What's your (simple/representative) HTML?

Comment: Use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: you will need a specific thing to identify the div you want to remove, either the order of th div, or a certain html attribute unique to the div. Otherwise you cannot 'select' it using a jquery 'selector'. Define the unique property of the div that you want to remove. If you are going by order look at the nth selector http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: You are right. I'd like to remove the one I chose.

Comment: What if I want to second the one I choose, $(".order_number_layer").find(this).remove(); right?

Comment: try my answer sung min yoon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/YULQm/)**

```
$('.order_del').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('div.order_number').remove();
});
```

Comment: +1. Mahahabol mo na ako ah.=D

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally working well. You saved my life! What a beautiful world!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','.order_del', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: remove the div not the button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$(".Order_del").find("div").slice(3).remove();`

in slice parameter you can specify the particular `div` `position number`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.order_del', function(){
        $('div.order_del:nth-of-type(1n)').remove();
    });
```

this will remove the second div with class order_del.

Answer (score 0):

In document of [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) have examples.

This example is for when you click on a button to delete an item with **.order_del** class.

```
$("button").click(function () {
$(".order_del").remove();
});
```

Is valide by name **class** and any element.